# Capitalize the first letter of the first word and the words in unconditionally capitalized array

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is the code I tried

```js
function sentenceCase(str, unconditionallyCapitalized) {
  let array = str
  str = str.toLowerCase().split(' ')
  console.log(str)
  // str.toUpperCase()
  unconditionallyCapitalized = unconditionallyCapitalized.join().toLowerCase()
  console.log(unconditionallyCapitalized)
  for (var x = 1; x <= array.length; x++) {
    str[0] = str[0].toUpperCase()
    if (str[x].includes('.')) {
      console.log(str[x])

    }
    if (unconditionallyCapitalized.includes(str[x])) {
      str[x] = str[x].split('')
      str[x][0] = str[x][0].toUpperCase()
      str[x] = str[x].join('')
      //console.log(str[x])
    }
  }

  return str.join(' ')
}


let str = 'I watched the storm, so beautiful yet terrific. The face of the moon was in shadow.';
let unconditionallyCapitalized = ['I', 'Moon', 'Shadow'];
console.log(sentenceCase(str, unconditionallyCapitalized));
```

So the above code gives me Moon but not Shadow and also the 'The' after terrific should be capitalized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try next code:

```js
  function findAndCapitalize(str, arrStr) {
        let tempStr = upperFirstLetter(str);
        arrStr.forEach(item => {
            let index = str.indexOf(item.toLowerCase());
            if(index !== -1) {
                let startPart = tempStr.substring(0, index),
                    endPart = tempStr.substring(index + item.length);
                tempStr = startPart + upperFirstLetter(item) + endPart;
            }
        })
        return tempStr;

        function upperFirstLetter(str) {
            let res = str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.substring(1);
            return res;
        }
    }
    let str = 'I watched the storm, so beautiful yet terrific. The face of the moon was in shadow.';
    let unconditionallyCapitalized = ['I', 'Moon', 'Shadow'];
console.log(findAndCapitalize(str, unconditionallyCapitalized));
```

Comment: This has no explanation.

Answer (score 0):

To make this a more helpful answer: 
`unconditionallyCapitalized.join().toLowerCase()` got you a string `i,moon,shadow` which is less helpful than an array of ['i', 'moon', 'shadow'] (which is what the `map` function I replaced it with gives you)

When a word has a period, you're just console.log-ing it. Instead, you can capitalize the word after it `str[x+1]` (which will be the first word in the new sentence).

I replaced your split/toUpperCase/join sequence with [string slicing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice).

And finally, you did not need to go to `x <=array.length`, just `x<array.length`. The extra index was causing an error cause it could not find anything at that index.

```js
function sentenceCase(str, unconditionallyCapitalized) {

        str = str.toLowerCase().split(' ')
        unconditionallyCapitalized = unconditionallyCapitalized.map(item=>{return item.toLowerCase()})
        str[0] = str[0].toUpperCase()
        for (var x = 1; x < str.length; x++) {
            if (str[x].includes('.') && str[x+1]) {
                str[x+1] = str[x+1].slice(0, 1).toUpperCase() + str[x+1].slice(1)
            } else if (str[x].includes('.')) {
                str[x] = str[x].slice(0, -1)
            }
            if (unconditionallyCapitalized.includes(str[x])) {
                str[x] = str[x].slice(0, 1).toUpperCase() + str[x].slice(1)
            }
        }

        return str.join(' ') + '.'
    }


    var str = 'I watched the storm, so beautiful yet terrific. the face of the moon was in shadow.';
    var unconditionallyCapitalized = ['I', 'Moon', 'Shadow'];


var answer =  sentenceCase(str, unconditionallyCapitalized)
console.log(answer)
```

Comment: sure! so the first thing is that you weren't doing anything to the words with periods in them, just console.logging them. The second thing is that it's easier to check `.includes` for array `['i', 'moon', 'shadow']` than string `"i,moon,shadow"`. Also! you were going to  `x <= array.length` and you just needed `x < array.length`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a modern approach to it. The key here is using [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) on the array to check if the word in your list (array) of words you want capitalized matches the current word you are iterating over (after breaking the string into an array via white space).

The `.replace(/\W/g, '')` removes all the non-word characters from your word, which allows `shadow.` to match `Shadow` (after being lower cased of course).

```js
const cleanString = str => str.replace(/\W/g, '').toLowerCase();
const capitalizeCertainWords = (str, words) =>
    str
        .split(' ')
        .map(
            word =>
                words.find(
                    capitalizedWord =>
                        cleanString(word) === cleanString(capitalizedWord)
                )
                    ? word.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + word.substring(1)
                    : word
        )
        .join(' ');

const str =
    'I watched the storm, so beautiful yet terrific. The face of the moon was in shadow.';
const unconditionallyCapitalized = ['I', 'Moon', 'Shadow'];

console.log(
    capitalizeCertainWords(str, unconditionallyCapitalized)
);
```